# tinylog formatting for double values

Tags: java, logging, scientific-notation, tinylog

I use tinylog for logging to file and console both. And I face with issue, that when I write to log double numbers, it's displayed in scientific (exponential) notation. For example, I have such line in my code:

```
Logger.info("Community with ID="+community.getDouble(ID_PROPERTY)+" was joined");
```

where *community.getDouble(ID_PROPERTY)* returns for example *50512447*. But in logs (log-file or console) it looks like *5.0512447E7*. How can I have the number display without scientific notation?

Comment: Is the return type of `community.getDouble(ID_PROPERTY)` `Double` or `double`? Is the number always an integer value?

Comment: @Tunaki, it returns simple double (not wrapper class)

Comment: @Tunaki as for your second question - I can't to answer exactly, I get this values via API and don't know how it's generated there.